# How to return a column id that contains minimum value in a 2-D array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to return the index of the column which contains the minimum value in a matrix, but so far i can only return the minimum value of the matrix, and can't figure out how to return that column's id. If I try to return "col" it doesn't change anything.

```
public static int minColIndex (int[][] m) {

        int row = m.length, col = m[0].length; 
        int min = m[0][0]; 
        for (col = 0; col < m.length; col++) {
            for (row = 0; row < m[col].length; row++) {
                if (min > m[col][row]) {
                    min = m[col][row];
                }
            }
        }
        return min; 

    }
```

Comment: You have wrongly pointing `row` and `col` in a matrix. On an `m x n` matrix, m and n represent rows and columns respectively. And hence, in a `m[][]` matrix, each of `[]` represent `row` and `col` respectively in sequence. If value 6 is in 2nd row, 4th col, then we write as `row=1; col=3; value = 6; m[ row ][ col ] = value;`

Comment: @Ravinder That depends on whether you wish to look at it as a matrix in row-major or column-major order, but I agree, the OP is confused on this point

Comment: thank you so much for pointing this out, that was pretty stupid of me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the value of `col` will always be `m.length - 1` after the outer loop completes. You need to store the minimum column somewhere, e.g.,

```
public static int minColIndex (int[][] m) {

    int row = m.length, col = m[0].length; 
    int min = m[0][0]; 
    int minCol = 0; // extra variable to store minimumm column
    for (col = 0; col < m.length; col++) {
        for (row = 0; row < m[col].length; row++) {
            if (min > m[col][row]) {
                min = m[col][row];
                minCol = col; // remember the minimum column as well as minimum
            }
        }
    }
    return minCol; // return minimum column, not col

}
```

There's also no need for `row` and `col` to have initial values set before the loop, so you can change the first few lines of the method to be the following, for slightly greater clarity:

```
public static int minColIndex (int[][] m) {
    int min = m[0][0]; 
    int minCol = 0; // extra variable to store minimumm column
    for (int col = 0; col < m.length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < m[col].length; row++) {

        ... etc.
```

Comment: i don't think this works - with the matrix like { {100, 2, 3},
         {4, 5, 6},
         {7, 8, 9}} it returns column index 0, which is wrong

Comment: I think you're confused as to which index you're calling "row" and which you're calling "column"

Comment: thank you for the explanation, now that i see that i had row and column mixed up, i fixed it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int minColIndex (int[][] m) {
        int row = m.length, col = m[0].length , int index = 0; 
        int min = m[0][0]; 
        for (col = 0; col < m.length; col++) {
            for (row = 0; row < m[col].length; row++) {
                if (min > m[col][row]) {
                    min = m[col][row];
                    index= col;
                }
            }
        }
        return index; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define these variables.

```
int rowOfMinValue = 0;
int colOfMinValue = 0;
```

And then,

Change:

```
if (min > m[col][row]) {
    min = m[col][row];
}
```

To:

```
if (min > m[col][row]) {
    min = m[col][row];

    rowOfMinValue = row;
    colOfMinValue = col;
}
```

now, you have min values row and column in hand.

**Suggestion**:
You have wrongly pointing `row` and `col` in a matrix. On an `m x n` matrix, `m` and `n` represent *rows* and *columns* respectively. And hence, in a `m[][]` matrix, each of `[]` represent `row` and `col` respectively in sequence.

If value `6` is in `2nd row`, `4th col`, then we write as

```
row=1; 
col=3; 
value = 6; 
m[ row ][ col ] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If(min< m[c][r]){
min=[c][r];
save=c;
}  '